# Binary serialization, IFormatter: use a new one each time or store one in a field?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Using binary formatting for 1st time in .net C#

Code from MSDN is like this:

```
 IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.lvl", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
 formatter.Serialize(stream, Globals.CurrentLevel);
 stream.Close();
```

Just wondering should I store an `IFormatter` in a field in my class and use it over and over again  or should I do as above and instantiate a new one every time I save/load something?

I noticed it is not `IDisposable`.

Comment: You can use the same one over and over again as long as you use it in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: what are your requirements / constraints? Or are you just wondering what would be best practice in general?

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering does it use up a lot of memory or something.. You should post this as answer!

Comment: @Default.. Yeah. I'm wondering best practice. as mentioned in last comment just wondering about memory leaks and such

Comment: Your stream creation and use should be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: @ Slicer. OK I tried a using statement on the Iformatter and got the error that it is not Idisposable

Comment: @GuyeIncognito as I said, on the STREAM creation, not the `IFormatter`.

Comment: Yeah. I read you.. I was just mentioning that I tried it on iformatter but not on stream :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's very little overhead in re-creating a `BinaryFormatter`, most of the properties it sets in the constructor are `enum`s, see here (thanks to Reflector):

```
public BinaryFormatter()
{
    this.m_typeFormat = FormatterTypeStyle.TypesAlways;
    this.m_securityLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
    this.m_surrogates = null;
    this.m_context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All);
}
```

If you were going to re-use it though, you'd need to synchronize access to the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods to keep them thread-safe.

Comment: isn't read on any object per se thread safe? Since the binaryformatter gets the stream as argument it's not modifying any of its internal fields (I guess) - thus why need to synchronize the access to it?

Comment: @Default You're right, updated. I think I was being overly-protective on the thread safety :)

Comment: well, I'm not sure, De/serialize could as well modify something, for instance storing the stream / writing to an internal buffer before writing to stream or similar. In that case, synchronization would be needed.. It was worth noting however :)

Comment: I can't say for certain, however `Serialize` is modifying internal state on an internal field named `m_crossAppDomainArray`, but so far as I can tell, it's only ever writing to it during Serialize, and only read from doing Deserialize. So the formatter is not thread safe if it is being used to both serialize and deserialize. However, this seems like an implementation detail that might change in a later version of .NET. I don't think it is intended to be thread safe.

Comment: @vcsjones Then maybe it should be synchronised just to be on the safe side (my original thoughts), rolled back my edit.